# I want to create a page that captures input from users, and that input spans multiple sObjects

Tags: unit-test

I have the VF code as below:

```
<apex:page controller="Customer">
      <apex:form >
          <apex:pageBlock title="New Customer Entry">
             <p>First Name:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!firstName}"/></p>
              <p>Last Name:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!lastName}"/></p>
              <p>Company Name:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!companyName}"/></p>
              <p># Employees:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!numEmployees}"/></p>
              <p>Department:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!department}"/></p>
              <p>Email:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!email}"/></p>
              <p>Phone:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!phone}"/></p>
              <p>Title:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!title}"/></p>
              <p>Address</p>
              <p>Street:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!streetAddress}"/></p>
              <p>City:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!cityAddress}"/></p>
              <p>State:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!stateAddress}"/></p>
              <p>Zip:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!postalCodeAddress}"/></p>
              <p>Country:
                 <apex:inputText value="{!countryAddress}"/></p>

              <p><apex:commandButton action="{!save}"
                 value="Save New Customer"/></p>
          </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountList}" var="acct">
              <apex:column value="{!acct.Name}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!acct.NumberOfEmployees}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="item">
              <apex:column value="{!item.Name}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Phone}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Title}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Department}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Email}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

And the controller code as below:

```
public class Customer 
{  
  public PageReference Submit() 
   {
     Customer__c cu=new Customer__c();
      {
        cu.FirstName__c=firstName;              
        cu.LastName__c=lastName;                
        cu.Company__c=companyName;                
        cu.city__c=cityAddress;                
        cu.Country__c=countryAddress;                
        cu.Department__c=department;       
        cu.email__c=email;                 
        cu.Employees__c=numEmployees;               
        cu.pin__c=postalCodeAddress ;        
        cu.Phonenumber__c=phone;                            
        cu.StAddress__c=streetAddress;                
        cu.state__c=stateAddress;               
        cu.Title__c=title;
       // insert cu;
        return null;

      }       
   }

   public String lastName {get; set;}
   public String firstName {get; set;}
   public String companyName {get; set;}
   public Integer numEmployees {get; set;}
   public String streetAddress {get; set;}
   public String cityAddress {get; set;}
   public String stateAddress {get; set;}
   public String postalCodeAddress {get; set;}
   public String countryAddress {get; set;}
   public String department {get; set;}
   public String email {get; set;}
   public String phone {get; set;}
   public String title {get; set;}          

      public String getName() {
          return 'Customer';
      }

   public void save() 
    {      
       Account a = new Account(
           Name = companyName,
           NumberOfEmployees = numEmployees,
           ShippingStreet = streetAddress,
           ShippingCity = cityAddress,
           ShippingState = stateAddress,
           ShippingPostalCode = postalCodeAddress,
           ShippingCountry = countryAddress);

       insert a;

       Contact c = new Contact(
           FirstName = firstName,
           LastName = lastName,
           Account = a,
           Department = department,
           Email = email,
           Phone = phone,
           Title = title,
           MailingStreet = streetAddress,
           MailingCity = cityAddress,
           MailingState = stateAddress,
           MailingPostalCode = postalCodeAddress,
           MailingCountry = countryAddress);

       insert c;
    }

       public List<Account> getAccountList() 
        {
           return [select name, numberofemployees from account];
        }

       public List<Contact> getContactList() 
        {
           return [select name, title, department, email, phone from contact];
        }

  }
```

The test method which i tried to get code coverage is below:

```
@istest
public class Customertest
{
   static testmethod void test()
    {
      Customer cu=new Customer();
      cu.firstName='';
      cu.lastName='';
      cu.companyName='';
      cu.cityAddress='';
      cu.countryAddress='';
      cu.department='';
      cu.email='';
      cu.numEmployees=10;
      cu.postalCodeAddress='';
      cu.phone='';
      cu.streetAddress='';
      cu.stateAddress='';
      cu.title='';
      cu.Submit();

      List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>{};

      for(Integer i = 0; i < 20; i++)
       {
          Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account ' + i);
          accounts.add(a);
       }

       test.startTest();
       insert accounts;
       test.stopTest();

       List<Account> insertedAccounts = [SELECT Name, Description
                                        FROM Account
                                        WHERE Id IN :accounts];

       List< Contact> contacts = new List< Contact>{};

       for(Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
          Contact c = new  Contact();
          contacts.add(c);
        }                   


       List<Contact> insertedContacts = [SELECT Name, Description
                                        FROM Contact
                                        WHERE Id IN    
                                        :contacts];                                       

    }
}
```

Comment: i am Getting only 72% code coverage. What should i do to get 100% code coverage

Answer (score 0):

To get coverage for a controller, you need to instantiate the controller in your test methods, and test the methods within your controller

```
@istest
public class Customertest{

   static testmethod void test() {

        PageReference pg = Page.YourPageName;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pg);        

        Customer controller = new Customer();
        controller.firstname = 'test first name';
        controller.lastname = 'test last name';
        //continue to set values for your controller properties like above

        list<Account> myAccounts = controller.getAccountList();
        list<Contact> myContacts = controller.getContactList();

        controller.submit();

        controller.save();

   }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but the test is failed and the error message was System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Name]: [Name]

Comment: When i tried to run the code only 72% is getting covered. The reason which i found is that the code coverage is not done from the List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>{}; which i gave in the test method.What should i do so that i get full code coverage

Comment: You need to add values for all of your controller properties as I indicated with a comment within the code.  Your account name is not being set, which is causing the error.